# using the same javascript file but load different data each time during an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

- I've got a javascript array with multiple variables....
- I am looping through this array
- during each loop, I am calling `function print_tag`

**Below is the first function**

```
function print_tags(all_tags,quantity_to_print) {
var print_array = all_tags.split(',');

let i = 0;
do { 
print_tag(print_array[i],quantity_to_print,i);
i++;
} while (i < print_array.length); 
}
```

All this is doing is taking the array and looping through each array entry and running another function that contains the AJAX.

```
function print_tag(tag,quantity_to_print,v) { 

    setTimeout(function() { 
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  ajaxI: v,
  url: "<?php echo http() . $websitedomain .'/Manage/js/DYMO/print_barcode.php'; ?>",
  data: { "inv_id": tag, "lcount": quantity_to_print },
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data){

      $('#resultDiv_' + tag).html(data);
      console.log(tag);

  } 
});

    }, 15000 * v);

}
```

All of this is to point out that the page the AJAX function is calling is using a SINGLE javascript file.  It is a file that prints labels out on a DYMO label printer.  Under normal scenerios, this works fine because I am sending 1 label to be printed each time; however, I'm now running a page that needs to send multiple (sometimes up to 24) different tags that need to be printed.  Each tag is sent through an individual AJAX request.  The PHP page is loading the correct data because I can see the output both in HTML and also in the console; however, the javascript file is printing the same tag each time.  The javascript file isnt refreshing to the new tag information.  I'm not sure if the javascript file is not being reloaded, or if it is somehow retaining information.  Below is the javascript file....

My first thought is maybe the javascript file isnt "closing" and just being recalled which prints another of the previous tags.  But I'm not a javascript expert so that may be crazy talk.  But each time the javascript file loads, I need it to input NEW data and not the exact same data from the first tag.

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  $Id: TextMarkup.js 38773 2015-09-17 11:45:41Z nmikalko $ 
//
// Project -------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  DYMO Label Framework
//
// Content -------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  DYMO Label Framework JavaScript Library Samples: Text Markup
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
//  Copyright (c), 2011, Sanford, L.P. All Rights Reserved.
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------


(function()
{
    // stores loaded label info
    var label;

    function escapeXml(xmlStr)
    {
        var result = xmlStr;
        var findReplace = [[/&/g, "&amp;"], [/</g, "&lt;"], [/>/g, "&gt;"], [/"/g, "&quot;"]];

        for(var i = 0; i < findReplace.length; ++i) 
            result = result.replace(findReplace[i][0], findReplace[i][1]);

        return result;
    }


    // addition                 
function repeat(func, times) {
    func();
    --times && repeat(func, times);
}


    // called when the document completly loaded
    function onload()
    {

         var textMarkupInput = document.getElementById('textMarkupInput');
        //var printTextMarkupButton = document.getElementById('printTextMarkupButton');
        var split = textMarkupInput.value.split(' | ');



        //var printersSelect = document.getElementById('printersSelect');
        //var printer = 'DYMO LabelWriter 450 Twin Turbo';
        //var printer = 'DYMO LabelWriter 4XL';
        var printer = split[0];
        //var textInput = document.getElementById('textInput');
        //var printButton = document.getElementById('printButton');






        // loads all supported printers into a combo box 
        function loadPrinters()
        {
            var printers = dymo.label.framework.getPrinters();
            if (printers.length === 0)
            {
                alert("No DYMO printers are installed. Install DYMO printers.");
                return;
            }

          /*  for (var i = 0; i < printers.length; i++)
            {
                var printer = printers[i];
                if (printer.printerType == "LabelWriterPrinter")
                {
                    var printerName = printer.name;

                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.value = printerName;
                    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(printerName));
                    printersSelect.appendChild(option);
                }
            }*/
        }











        //printTextMarkupButton.onclick = function()
        $( document ).ready(function()

        {
            try
            {
                if (!label)
                {
                    alert("Load label before printing");
                    return;
                }

                // set data using LabelSet and text markup
                var labelSet = new dymo.label.framework.LabelSetBuilder();
                var record = labelSet.addRecord();







                var SKU = '';
                var DESCRIPTION = '';
                var BARCODE = '';
                var NETWEIGHT = '';
                var GROSSWEIGHT = '';




                SKU += '<b>';
                SKU += split[3];
                SKU += '</b>';

                DESCRIPTION += '<b>Description</b><br />';
                DESCRIPTION += split[4];


                BARCODE += split[5];

                console.log(split[5]);

                NETWEIGHT += '<b>';
                NETWEIGHT += split[6];
                NETWEIGHT += '</b>';

                GROSSWEIGHT += '<b>';
                GROSSWEIGHT += split[7];
                GROSSWEIGHT += '</b>';


                record.setTextMarkup('SKU', SKU);
                record.setTextMarkup('DESCRIPTION', DESCRIPTION);
                record.setTextMarkup('BARCODE', BARCODE);
                record.setTextMarkup('NETWEIGHT', NETWEIGHT);
                record.setTextMarkup('GROSSWEIGHT', GROSSWEIGHT);





repeat(function () { 


//regular code

                                //setlabel(labelSetBuilder);
//var params = dymo.label.framework.createLabelWriterPrintParamsXml({twinTurboRoll: dymo.label.framework.TwinTurboRoll.Right});
    var params = dymo.label.framework.createLabelWriterPrintParamsXml({twinTurboRoll: split[1]});
                //var params = '';

                //label.print(printersSelect.value, params, labelSet.toString());
                label.print(printer, params, labelSet.toString());




// addition
}, lcount); 






            }
            catch(e)
            {
                alert(e.message || e);
            }



        });











        function getAddressLabelXml() {



        function loadXMLDoc(theURL)
    {
        if (window. XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, SeaMonkey
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", theURL +'?_=' + new Date().getTime(), false);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

        var xmlhttp=false;
//loadXMLDoc('https://www.americanstrapping.com/Manage/js/DYMO/STEEL_STRAPPING_LARGE_LABEL.label');
loadXMLDoc(split[2] +'.label');

if(xmlhttp==false){ alert('NOPE'); }
else { return xmlhttp.responseText; }   




        }

        function loadLabelFromWeb()
        {            





            // use jQuery API to load label
           // $.get("Address.label", function(labelXml)

           // {



            label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(getAddressLabelXml());


            // }, "text");
        }

        loadLabelFromWeb();
        // load printers list on startup
        loadPrinters();
    };

    function initTests()
    {



        if(dymo.label.framework.init)
        {
            //dymo.label.framework.trace = true;
            dymo.label.framework.init(onload);
        } else {
            onload;
        }
    }




        window.onload = initTests();


} ());
```

BELOW IS THE DATA BEING SENT TO LAST JAVASCRIPT CODE...YOU CAN SEE THAT THE BARCODES ARE DIFFERENT....

1. DYMO LabelWriter 450 Twin Turbo | Left |
   https://www.......com/Manage/js/DYMO/STEEL_STRAPPING_SMALL_LABEL
   | HSE-HT24114-TEST-NCW | 1-1/4" X .024 HSE-HT TEST MATERIAL |
   **TEST-126725** | 600 | 645
2. DYMO LabelWriter 450 Twin Turbo | Left |
   https://www......com/Manage/js/DYMO/STEEL_STRAPPING_SMALL_LABEL
   | HSE-HT24114-TEST-NCW | 1-1/4" X .024 HSE-HT TEST MATERIAL |
   **TEST-795061** | 600 | 645

But no matter how many times I loop through, Label 1 prints every single time.  It never goes to the other data.

Comment: could it be the javascript file caching?  And it can only be called once because the actual website hasnt reloaded, just sending a new AJAX call?

Comment: the problem IS occuring inside the javascript file.  The correct data is being sent to it but it is simply looping through the first data that was sent to it.  The javascript file isnt recognizing a change in data.  How can this be?

Comment: and just for reference.  I've already got `.js?version=<?php echo time(); ?>` in my code on all my js files to prevent caching of the actual files.